# Некорректно рендерится ссылка в markdown в истории описания метки

Tags: дефект, markdown, описание-метки

There's a broken link in the tag description history. The following markdown syntax isn't rendered as it should:

```
[text[tag-name]](/relative-link)
```

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

However, in the question body the same syntax is rendered as intended. (This *relative* link leads to 404, because we're not on the main site.)

```
[Вернуться к описанию [архитектура]](/tags/%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%85%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0/info)
```

> [Вернуться к описанию [архитектура]](/tags/%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%85%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0/info)

Looks like the text was not processed by a markdown renderer. If that's not the issue, then escaping the literal braces might help:

```
[Вернуться к описанию \[архитектура\]](/tags/%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%85%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0/info)
```

> [Вернуться к описанию [архитектура]](/tags/%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%85%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0/info)

Comment: Можно подправить [перевод в transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/51045912?key=9fe4815d55133233c371f8052b8369cb) путём добавления обратных слэшей. Хотя он вроде как работал после утверждения. И, кстати, с Меты ссылки ведут на мета-метку, т.е. 404.

Comment: @alexolut я и имел в виду 404. А слеши не факт, что помогут. Возможно, строку просто не пропустили через рендерер markdown.

Comment: Э-э ... ничего не понял про 404. Ну, лучше, конечно, чтобы парсер в заголовке работал так же как и в теле, это да.

Comment: @alexolut более явно написал про 404.

Answer (score 1):

Были добавлены экранирующие обратные слэши, как предложено в вопросе.

[Локализованная строка в transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/51045912?key=9fe4815d55133233c371f8052b8369cb) выглядит так:

> `[Вернуться к описанию \[$tagName$\]]($url$)`

На текущий момент проблема не проявляется.